# Reset input type file using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to clear/reset input type file within Vue.js 2
Before I've used jQuery method clone:

```
var input = $(div).find("input[type='file']");
input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
```

How can I clear this input? I can't use v-model for input because it doesn't work in vue 2

Comment: adding a `<input type='reset'/>` can  do this.

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh this is not an option for my usecase, I have a lot of fields in this form.

Comment: you can use https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref ref vue js attribute to hold that node reference and then when you want to clear you can do => vm.$refs.fileupload.value= null;

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I've tested this - not working for IE 11, and default browser on Android 4.4

Comment: are you adding jquery in your project or just vue, if you are adding jquery then you can do same stuff as you do before but now input can be var input = $(vm.$refs.fileupload)

Comment: also tried. v-on:change is being resetted, so any vue events should be refreshed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59659243/9272654

Answer (score 2):

it works.

```
<input type="file" ref="myFileInput"/>


this.$refs.myFileInput.value = '';
```

Reference : https://jj.isgeek.net/2018/02/how-to-reset-file-input-with-vuejs/

Answer (score 1):

My old site used your same method when I was using AngularJS. I'm currently converting to use Vue and ran into the same issue. Here is what I did to solve my problem.

```
fileInput.file = null
```

or

```
$('#fileInput')[0].file = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reset_document()
{this.instructions_file_document = "";
$("input[type=file]").val(null);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above, but my project had several errors.
What solved my problem was:

```
<input type="file" ref="inputFile"/>

this.$refs.inputFile.reset();
```

This code above resets the field values.