# How to reset/clear file Input

Tags: file, vue.js, input, types, reset

I am stuck with this problem from resetting an image file from input type=file. This is the scenario,
I set an image and then I clicked the 'Cancel' button (which means it was reset), and then I will set again the same image, it will not set. I do not know why but I think it is a bug.

Here is my code for resetting the image/form.

```js
resetImage() {
    this.$refs.addImageForm.reset()
    this.dialog = ''
    this.imgSrc = ''
    this.fileName = ''
    this.imgUrl = ''
    this.file = ''
}
```

I am using `Vue.js` and `Vuetify` if that helps. I hope you can help me. I am stuck with this problem

HERE IS THE HTML

```html
<template>
    <v-dialog
        persistent
        v-model="dialog"
        width="600"
    >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn depressed color="primary" v-on="on">
        <v-icon class="pr-2">check</v-icon>Approve
        </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
        <div class="px-4 pt-3">
            <span class="subheading font-weight-bold">Approve Details</span>
            <input
                ref="image"
                type="file"
                name="image"
                accept="image/*"
                style="display: none;"
                @change="setImage"
            />
            <v-layout row wrap align-center>
                <v-flex xs12 class="pa-0">
                <div class="text-xs-center">
                    <v-img :src="imgUrl" contain/>
                </div>
                <VueCropper
                    :dragMode="'none'"
                    :viewMode="1"
                    :autoCrop="false"
                    :zoomOnWheel="false"
                    :background="false"
                    :src="imgSrc"
                    v-show="false"
                    ref="cropper"
                />
                <v-form ref="addImageForm" lazy-validation>
                    <v-layout row wrap class="pt-2">
                    <v-flex xs12>
                        <v-text-field
                        outline
                        readonly
                        :label="imgSrc ? 'Click here to change the image' : 'Click here to upload image'"
                        append-icon='attach_file'
                        :rules="imageRule"
                        v-model='fileName'
                        @click='launchFilePicker'
                        ></v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                </v-form>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </div>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-card-actions class="px-4">
        <v-btn
            large
            flat
            @click="resetImage()"
        >Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn
            large
            depressed
            color="primary"
            @click="approveCashout"
            :loading="isUploading"
        >Approve</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: Sure2 wait I will edit

Comment: Updated and added html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `ref` to reset the file uploader value.

```js
this.$refs.fileupload.value = null;
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/MWYVjqP?editors=1010

Comment: In my setup - Vue 2.6.12, Vuetify 2.4.2, Typescript 3.9.7 this results in a 'Vue warning': "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. [...]"

It still works, but so does the answer below (besides vs code reporting a nonexistent error)

Comment: this throws an error `Cannot set property 'value' of undefined"`

Comment: @MohamedRaza Make sure you have added ref in input field

Comment: @PatelPratik i already added ref in my input

Comment: @MohamedRaza Can you try to console log this.$refs.fileupload and check it's giving value or not

Comment: For `this.$refs.fileupload.value=null;` to work, you need to assign ref on the input as well like this `<input ref="fileupload" type="file" />`.

Comment: Yup it's required. It's there in codepen and question.

Comment: Works like charm and no warning, Vue.js 2.6.11

Answer (score 15):

To reset the input, I let vue rerender it. Just add a key to the input and change the value of the key whenever you want the file input to be cleared.

Like so:

```js
window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fileInputKey: 0
  },
  methods:{
    inputChange() {
      console.log('files chosen');
    },
    clear() {
        this.fileInputKey++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" @change="inputChange($event)" :key="fileInputKey"/>
  <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Of all the solutions, this was the only one that works :)

Answer (score 13):

I tried several suggestions I found on Stackoverflow, but in my project there were several errors.
What solved my problem was:

```html
<input type="file" ref="inputFile"/>
```

```js
this.$refs.inputFile.reset();
```

This code above resets the field values.

Comment: the above answer throws some warning. this one should be the accepted answer

Comment: I get `TypeError: this.$refs.inputFile.reset is not a function` when I use this, but using `this.$refs.inputFile.value=null` worked for me.

Comment: this.$refs.inputFile.$el.value=null
is better

Comment: work like a charm, this is the right way how to reset the file input form on vuetify. Thanks

Comment: This does not work for me, says reset is not a function and removing brackets doesn't do anything. Neither warning nor error and nothing happens, Vue.js 2.6.11

Answer (score 7):

I also came to this problem and could not reset the value. after going through the code of all previous projects and modifying them I got a lot of methods through which a file input could be reset.
one of the way is do is to capture the event object if you want to perform it after handling some code. another way is to change the type of the input element and change it back again.

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" @change="onFilePicked" ref="file">
  <button @click="clear()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

```js
var v = new Vue({
    el:'#app',

    data:{},

    methods:{
        clear() { 
            this.$refs.file.type='text';    
            this.$refs.file.type='file'; 
        },
        onFilePicked(event){
            //if you directly want to clear the file input after handling 
            //some code........
            event.target.value=null;
            //OR
            event.target.value='';
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Composition api**

```html
<input type="file" 
       class="custom-file-input" 
       id="customFileLang" 
       lang="en" 
       accept="image/*"
       :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors && errors.images }"
       @change="previewImg" multiple
>
```

Inside setup function:

```js
const imgInput = ref(null) // for input type file

const previewImg = (event) => {
    imgInput.value = event
    // rest of code to preview img
}

const uploadImage = () => {
    //on success
    imgInput.value.target.value = null //reset input type file
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Vue 2 or 3 or Nuxt with composition API, you can use this to reset a form:

```js
<template>
  <form ref="refForm">
    <input value="hello world" />
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
const refForm = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    refForm.value.reset()
  }, 3000) // in 3 seconds will reset the form
})
</script>
```

to reset only the input file, use this code:

```js
<template>
  <input ref="refFile" type="file" @change="reset" />
</template>

<script setup>
const refFile = ref(null)

const reset = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    refFile.value.value = ''
  }, 3000) // in 3 seconds will reset the file input
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanyou, im forgot when using ref must use value.value haha.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vue 3 Composition API, here's how I was able to do it:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input ref="fileInput" type="file" />

    <button @click.prevent="clearFiles">Clear files</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue"

const fileInput = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

function clearFiles() {
  fileInput.value!.value = ""
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try mutilpe ways on vue, the best way is:

define this method:

```
removePic(inp) {
  if (this.$refs[inp].files.length === 0) return
  this.$refs[inp].files = []
  delete this.body[inp]
  this.$refs[`${inp}_preview`].src = ''
},
```

in the template use as this:

```
                   <b-form-file
                      ref="pic"
                      name="pic"
                      accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif"
                    />

                  <feather-icon
                    icon="XIcon"
                    size="18"
                    class="text-primary stroke-current"
                    @click="removePic('pic')"
                  />

                 <div>
                  <img ref="pic_preview" src="#" alt="select" />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
inputfile.files = new DataTransfer().files;

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you provided, it seems like the issue might be related to the way the file input field handles the same file selection after clicking the "Cancel" button. It could be a browser-specific behavior, where selecting the same file again does not trigger the change event on the file input.

To work around this issue, you can try the following approach:

Instead of resetting the form using this.$refs.addImageForm.reset(), manually clear the value of the file input field when canceling the image selection.

You can use a key variable to force the file input element to re-render when resetting the image, so that it can handle the same file selection again.

Here's how you can modify your code to implement these changes:

Add a key attribute to the file input element and bind it to a data property, for example, inputKey.

Set the inputKey to a new value whenever you want to reset the file input.

Clear the value of the file input field (set it to null) when canceling the image selection.

Here's the updated code for your Vue component:

```
<template>
  <!-- Your existing template code -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Existing data properties
      inputKey: 0, // Add a new data property for the key

      // Your other data properties
    };
  },
  methods: {
    launchFilePicker() {
      this.$refs.image.click();
    },
    setImage(event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = file.name;
        this.imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        // Increment the key to force re-render the file input element
        this.inputKey += 1;
      }
    },
    resetImage() {
      this.$refs.image.value = null; // Clear the value of the file input field
      this.dialog = "";
      this.imgSrc = "";
      this.fileName = "";
      this.imgUrl = "";
      this.file = "";
    },
    // Your other methods
  },
};
</script>
```

By resetting the file input value to null, you should be able to select the same image again after clicking the "Cancel" button. The inputKey variable ensures that the file input element re-renders and listens to the change event again.

Comment: Using ChatGPT to post answers is not allowed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).